# How to test readFragment in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am using Apollo + React + Jest.

I have data in Apollo cache, then I get data from it in React as well.

But I can't get data while testing.

Way of getting data is different between `readFragment` and `useQuery`.

So I can't use the same way to test `readFragment` in my unit test file.

I tried to mock `provider` and `client`, but it doesn't work.

Are there any solutions for `readFragment` in testing?

my react file

```
import React from "react";
import { useApolloClient } from "@apollo/react-hooks";

const FileInfo: React.FC<Props> = props => {
  const client = useApolloClient();
  const file = client.readFragment({
    id: `Rendition-222-333`,
    fragment: gql`
      fragment rendition on Rendition {
        status
        title
      }
    `,
  });

  return (
    <>
      <p> {file.status} </p>
      <p> {file.title} </p>
    </>
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend gave me a solution, I post it in here if someone needs it.

```
import { useApolloClient } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
jest.mock("@apollo/react-hooks");

describe("<FileInfo/>", () => {
  let useApolloClientMock: jest.Mock;
  beforeEach(() => {
    useApolloClientMock = useApolloClient as jest.Mock;
    useApolloClientMock.mockReturnValue({
      readFragment: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ status: "downloaded", title: "123test" }),
    });
  });

  afterEach(jest.resetAllMocks);

  test("When it renders Then it should not crash", () => {
    const { container } = setup();
    expect(container).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```